# Replicating nutrition label - expert CSS level

Tags: html, css

I am trying to emulate this nutrition label format in CSS, but I can't get the shapes right at all.  The best I can come up with is fiddling with border-radius, but that gives me more of a pill shape, and still not way to get the black cut-out shape at the bottom.  Has anyone replicated such a nutrition label in CSS?  Would anyone be willing to try?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a link to what I have so far: [jsfiddle.net/f5jczunf](http://jsfiddle.net/f5jczunf/)/

```
#block {
        border-radius:50%/10px;
        background: #ccc;
        padding: 20px; 
        width: 50px;
        height: 100px; 
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background-color:#FFF;
        text-align:center;
    }



.number {
          font-weight:bold;
          font-size:18pt;
          text-align:center;
        }

<div id="block">
<span class="number">150</span>
<br/>Calories
</div>
```

[image: Front of Package Nutrition Label]

Comment: the closest you could get is positioning two circles on either end of a rectangle to get the cynlinder shape.

Comment: Always willing to help and this looks very challengingly fun, but it is strongly encouraged for users seeking help of this nature to also include their attempts or at least the most recent one.  Can you update your question with the code of what you've tried so far?  It could also provide a springboard for us to start from.

Comment: You should at least try something before you basically ask for someone to write it for you. Try creating the cylinders first. Whatever the solution, it will require  a lot of layering most likely.

Comment: Your only "problem" seems to be not allocating sufficient resources to the task at hand. And you're mistaking SO for Upwork, Fiverr, Guru, Freelancer and the likes. SO is dedicated to helping you become a better programmer, not to providing free programming services. Your question should be in the form of ***Why isn't my code working, I think it should be***, rather than ***Please code this for me***...

Comment: @Wold I'll post what I have so far. It's basically just a vertical rectangle with rounded corners.  I need to get a fiddle up (never done that before).

Comment: Here is my fiddle (what I have so far): jsfiddle.net/f5jczunf/

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this small example can help.

```css
.label {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 100px/50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.title {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 100px/50px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="label">
  <span class="title">Title</span>
  <span class="bottom">Bottom</span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9xs2wcbL/1/

Answer (score 3):

Here's my take on it.  It does require some advanced, bleeding edge CSS, however.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300');
body {
  padding: 3em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}
.label-list {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.label-list .label-item {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2em / 0.65em;
  padding: 0.2em 0.25em 1.5em;
  min-width: 3.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0.1em;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
.label-list .label-item h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 0;
}
.label-list .label-item h1.smaller {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
.label-list .label-item h1 small {
  font-size: 0.4em;
  text-transform: none;
}
.label-list .label-item small {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.label-list .label-item span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.5em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.label-list .label-item span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: black;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 40%;
  transform-origin: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(20%, 20%);
}
```

```html
<div class="label-list">
  <div class="label-item">
    <h1>140</h1>
    <small>Calories</small>
  </div>
  <div class="label-item">
    <h1 class="smaller">1<small>g</small></h1>
    <small>Sat Fat</small>
    <span>5% DV</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very crazy, probably first time I saw anyone use matrix transformations :D

Comment: @Sandro They're really growing on me, but in this case, they're unnecessary.  I didn't use them for any skewing, so a simple rotate, scale, and border radius will accomplish the same thing. Still fun to use though.  I think I'll update the answer to use more reliable transforms.

Comment: Yeah they seem pretty cool, but I never got over poking around with them and for me they're useless because I don't (yet) know how to use them...

Comment: @Sandro Yeah, they are.  You kind of do need a tool that generates them to really use them effectively.  Minor stuff like a simple skew or rotate are fine, but otherwise it's just too much work to write them by hand.

Comment: Do you have such a tool? ^^

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to have this sort of shape in pure CSS is with a few overlapping shapes, something similar to the code below:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 112px;
  width: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rectangle,
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.rectangle {
  height: 96px;
  width: 80px;
  top: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: -60px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.top {
  top: 0;
}

.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle top"></div>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
  <div class="circle bottom"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dylanstark/01hck5dv/

Answer (score 0):

here my approach for that. I'm using `before` and `after` pseudo-elements.
`before` contains black bg with border-radius and it is overflowing the main `#block` which has `overflow: hidden;`. 
`after`contains text that is coming from `data-text` attribute of `#block`

```css
#block {
  border-radius: 50%/10px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#block:before {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  z-index: 0;
}
#block:after {
  display: block;
  content: attr(data-label);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
.number {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18pt;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="block" data-label="5% DY">
  <span class="number">150</span>
  <br/>Calories
</div>
```